# React-Admin, autocomplete Forms by onChange event

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Is it possible to auto fill in the Form by onChange Event?

Is it possible to access all the data that comes through a request by ReferenceInput?

```
const handleChange = (event, ...props) => {

};
```

---

```
<ReferenceInput label="User" source="user.id" onChange={handleChange} reference="user">
   <SelectInput fullWidth optionText="userDescription"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a custom `onChange` event, you should pass it inside inputProps property to ReferenceInput.

Something like this should work:

```
    <ReferenceInput
      inputProps={{
        onChange: e => {
          //your logic here
       },
      }}
    >
```

In the other hand, if you want to access to the data coming inside ReferenceInput, you can do your own component and receive the options as `choices` prop.